# Repeating an object or arrays within an Repeated object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to repeat an object or array of items within an object already repeated? As an example if I have this set up:

```
items = [
  {name: 'title', person: [ person1, person2, person3, etc. ]},
  {name: 'title2', person: [ person1, person2, person3, etc. ]}
]
```

And in the html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>{{item.person}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to loop the people in the person array. I do not want to just have the array of people in the that ONE li. Is there a way to accomplish this within an ng-repeat?

Comment: for that li use ng-repeat="person in item.person"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested `ng-repeat` can do that:

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in item.person">{{person}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```